# Can /proc/PID still exist when PID isn't running?

Tags: linux, process, proc

is it possible that a folder like `/proc/4587` exists even though there isn't a process that has PID 4587?

Comment: Are you wondering if checking for /proc/N is a safe/reliable way to see if PID N is running?

Comment: I was wondering if theoretically there could be residue in /proc after process is gone.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If `/proc` is only the `proc` mount (and no one is playing tricks with overlays), no, a pid-based folder only exists as long as the corresponding process exists in some state (including as a zombie). In fact, just before returning a directory entry for a process id, the [kernel re-validates the process’ existence](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/base.c#n2398) — so at the instant a directory entry is returned, the corresponding process is still there. [Accessing a directory](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/fs/proc/base.c#n2432) also starts by looking up the corresponding process. (If the line numbers change, look for `proc_pident_instantiate` and `proc_pident_lookup`.)

You can run into issues caused by listing `/proc` and using the results later (even a few microseconds later): a process can be running when you list `/proc`, and stop before you act on the results.

Comment: What about processes that finished execution but `wait()` hadn't been called on them?

Comment: Good point @el.pescado, a quick check indicates that zombie processes still have their directory. I’ll update my answer, thanks!

Comment: Basically, if `ps` shows the process, its `/proc` directory should exist.

Comment: @Barmar “must” in fact: `ps` accesses `/proc` to find the information it displays.